# Directory comparison

Tags: python

path1 : /home/users/term/R1.0/test/mw

path2 : /home/users/term/R1.2/test/mw

I would like to compare the above two directory paths and output the path which has highest version.

output = /home/users/term/R1.2/test/mw

What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: So you need this in python?, since you have tagged python but nowhere mentioned. What have you tried, code, error? Hint: split, compare, output.

Answer (score 0):

```
path1 = '/home/users/term/R1.0/test/mw'
path2 = '/home/users/term/R1.2/test/mw'

if path1.split('/')[4] > path2.split('/')[4]:
    print path1
else:
    print path2
```